# NULL arg allowed to sscanf?

Tags: c, scanf

Is a `NULL` pointer allowed as the string to store result in in a call to `sscanf`?

I don't find anything about it in any documentation but it seems to be working fine. Same thing with `scanf`.

Example:

```
int main(int arc, char* argv[])
{
  char* s = NULL;
  sscanf("Privjet mir!", "%s", s);
  printf("s: %s\n", s);
  return 0;
}
```

Output: `s: (null)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No:

> Matches a sequence of non-white-space
>   characters; the next pointer must be a
>   pointer to character array that is
>   long enough to hold the input sequence
>   and the terminating null character
>   ('\0'), which is added automatically.
>   The input string stops at white space
>   or at the maximum field width,
>   whichever occurs first.

(http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf)

Comment: This answer also teaches us that forbidding null doesn't need to mentions the word "null" explicitly. Stating that something must be "a pointer to <some specific kind of data>" implicitly forbids null.

Answer (score 5):

As is mentioned by the other answers `NULL` is not valid to pass to `sscanf` as an additional argument.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf says of additional arguments:

> Depending on the format string, the function may expect a sequence of additional arguments, each containing a **pointer to allocated storage where the interpretation of the extracted characters is stored with the appropriate type**.

[For the `%s` specifier these extracted characters are](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/#parameters):

> Any number of non-whitespace characters, stopping at the first whitespace character found. A terminating null character is automatically added at the end of the stored sequence.

So when the "non-whitespace characters" and "terminating null character" is stored, there will be a segfault. Which is exactly what Visual Studio will yield (you can test that this fails at http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/):

[image]

Now as far as non-Visual Studio compilers, libc's extraction code for the `%s` specifier: https://github.com/ffainelli/uClibc/blob/master/libc/stdio/_scanf.c#L1376 has the leading comment: `/* We might have to handle the allocation ourselves */` this is because:

> The GNU C library supported the dynamic allocation conversion specifier (as a nonstandard extension) via the `a` character. This feature seems to be present at least as far back as glibc 2.0.
>   Since version 2.7, glibc also provides the `m` modifier for the same purpose as the `a` modifier.

[[Source](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf)]

So because libc extracts to a buffer constructed internally to `sscanf` and subsequently checks that the buffer parameter has no flags set before assigning it, it will never write characters to a `NULL` buffer parameter.

I can't stress enough that this is non-standard, and is not guaranteed to be preserved even between minor library updates. A far better way to do this is to use the `*` sub-specifier which:

> Indicates that the data is to be read from the stream but ignored (i.e. it is not stored in the location pointed by an argument).

[[Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/#parameters)]

This could be accomplished like this for example:

```
s == NULL ? sscanf("Privjet mir!", "%*s") : sscanf("Privjet mir!", "%s", s);
```

Obviously the true-branch of the ternary is a no-op, but I've included it with the expectation that other data was expected to be read from the string.

Answer (score 2):

The manpage says that, when using `%s`, the argument must be a pointer with enough space for the string and `\0`. So my guess would be that the behaviour in your case is undefined. It may work, it may also crash or corrupt memory and cause issues later.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not allowed. 
sscanf %s expects a char* pointing to a sufficient large buffer, printf %s wants a nul  char*  buffer. Anything else results in undefined behavior. (And that means some implementations might detect and handle a null pointer in a certain way, other implementations might not)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find anything in the standard explicitly concerning `NULL` and `*printf`/`*scanf`.

I suppose that this is undefined behavior<sup>1</sup>, since it counts as passing an argument that is not coherent with the format specifier (§7.19.6.1 ¶13, §7.19.6.2 ¶13): `%s` means that a you're going to pass a pointer to the first element of a character array (large enough for the acquired string for `*scanf`, containing a `NUL`-terminated string for `*printf`) - and passing `NULL` doesn't satisfy this requirement.

---

1. In this case UB shows as "just ignoring the acquisition" and "printing (null)", on other platforms it may result in planes falling down the sky or the usual [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Answer (score -2):

Allocate the memory to s . Assign s to character array. Then run the program.
Following will work.

```
int main(int arc, char* argv[])
{
  char s[100];
  sscanf("Privjet mir!", "%[^\t]s", s);
  printf("s: %s\n", s);
  return 0;
}
```